# the image quality of imageButton goes down when I run the app

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to use an image button on my android app. The quality of the image is HD but when I run the app, the quality of the image deteriorates

this is the image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBSRN.png

its of great quality but when I run the app, the image quality becomes really bad.

Comment: are you sure the image is in the right folder? Check Android is not much resizing  it. To prove it is android resizing the problem, set to the ImageButton the exactly size of the image in PX. It will show you the real size of the image in the device.

Comment: Your image is 150 x 83 in size.  If you go above that, it will blur. I suggest find a bigger size image.

Comment: Scaling **upwards** will pixellate the image. Often, with horrible results. Scaling **downwards** would average the neighbouring pixels. The correct approach should be to have an image per each supported density (see the posts on the official developer site). Or use a **vector** (svg or VectorDrawable), instead of a **bitmap**. Other than this, your image only consists of a white **text** over a yellow background. So, why using an image at all? A truetype or opentype font (which are both **vectorial** ones) would do just fine. With the added ability of changing the text at any time.

Answer (score 0):

may the size is not the right size so it is stretching inside the button